# multivariate t location scale distribution

Tags: multivariate-distribution

I am following a procedure described in the book "understanding computational bayesian stastistics" pagg 176-178.

I need to generate a random sample from a multivariate T-location-scale distribution. and then evaluate the probability density.

The generation of the sample is really well explained and I have no problems with that. At the end of the procedure he says that the sampled vector $\theta=\{\theta_1,...\theta_p \}$ is a random draw from the multivariate Student's t [m,V] distribution with k degrees of freedom.

Now I need to evaluate the pdf but, in matlab the multivariate t pdf (mvtpdf command)

$y=mvtpdf(X,C,df)$

only accepts as input the vector of parameters $X$, the correlation matrix (or the covariance matrix, Matlab automatically rescales it) then $C=V$, and the degrees of freedom $k$.

Since I know the scaling vector $m$ can I evaluate the pdf using as input for $X$ the value $\theta-m$?

Is it correct?